# How to use SELECT IN clause in JDBCTemplates?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

This is my first experience with JDBCTemplates and I ran into a case where I need to use a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (?)
```

How do I do that? I already tried passing a list/array value but that didn't do the trick, I get an exception. My current code looks like this:

```
Long id = getJdbcTemplate().queryForLong(query, new Object[]{fieldIds});
```

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) states that there is no way of doing this besides generating the required number of "?" placeholders to match the size of the parameter List. Is there a workaround?

Comment: The SQL `IN` clause does not accept a single variable to represent a list of values -- no database does, without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case... I mean SELECT IN is as old as SQL itself, WTF!! I'm baffled there is no support for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this as a single '?'. It's nothing to do with Spring JDBC templates, it's core SQL.

You'll have to build up a (?, ?, ?) for as many of them as you need.

Comment: There is a workaround for this that doesn't require you to dynamically add "?" placeholders to the query. See my answer below.

Comment: unbelievable that this is the accepted answer. see the upvoted answer below.

Answer (score 52):

There is a workaround using [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) instead of [SimpleJdbcDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.html), where you can do something like this:

```
List integerList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
Map<String,Object> params = Collections.singletonMap("fields", integerList);    
Long id = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForLong("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (:fields)", params);
```

This, however, has a potentially catastrophic limitation regarding the number of parameters you can pass in the list which depends on the DB you are using.

Comment: It works.catastrophic limitation did not occur in my project.

Comment: @janwen the limitation has to do with the number of parameters you can pass to a IN clause, usually the limit is 1000, but as I said, this depends on the DB. 1000 is pretty high so on most cases you should be fine, that's probably your case

Comment: @Chepech is there any way we can increase limit ?

Comment: How to use it if I want to have a custom class object list (with RowMapper) as a result ?

Comment: @Vipin You do it in a two-step, in the same SQL transaction (really no need for transaction, but same context - i.e. don't close the Connection between): First make a temporary table, and insert your values there. Then you do the select with a one sided join, e.g. left join. Btw, you should probably delete the temp-table in a try-finally to clean up before letting the Connection go back to a DataSource pool or similar.

Answer (score 3):

For long list (ex. Oracle has limitation for 1000 items) you can just separate it to more selects:

```
List<Long> listIds = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, ..... , 10000L); // list with ids

String query = "select NOTE from NOTE where ID in (:listIds)";

List<String> noteListResult = new ArrayList<>();

int current = 0;
int iter = 100;

while (current < listIds.size()) {
    Map<String, List<Long>> noteIdsMap = Collections.singletonMap("listIds",
            listIds.subList(current, (current + iter > listIds.size()) ? listIds.size() : current + iter));

    List<String> noteListIter = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, noteIdsMap, String.class);
    noteListResult.addAll(noteListIter);

    current += iter;
}

return noteListResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with MapSqlParameterSource with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("array", inputarray);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbctemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
```

In query

IN (:array)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do it although I don't think it is the most correct. But I leave it here in case it helps someone.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ("+array.toString()+")
```

in this way jdbcTemplate reads the query as a complete string and it executes correctly.