# How to use a list of string in NamedParameterJDBCTemplate to get results

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Experimenting with Spring-JDBC. I am using [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) as reference. I am trying to get a list of actors who have the same last name. Running this code gave me the desired results:

```
public List<String> getActorsWithSameLastName(String lastName,
            NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {
        String query = "SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM ACTORS WHERE LASTNAME=:LASTNAME";
        Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paramMap.put("LASTNAME", lastName);
        return template.queryForList(query, paramMap, String.class);
    }
```

I have a `List<String>` of last names. How can I get a List of actors with the list that I have? Do I iterate over the list of last names and call the `getActorsWithSameLastName()` everytime or does spring provide a way where it does the iteration and fetches the result for me? Please advice.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use IN Clause..

[How to use SELECT IN clause in JDBCTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504592/how-to-use-select-in-clause-in-jdbctemplates)

```
List<String> lastnames= new ArrayList<>();

Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("lastnamevalues", lastnames);

StringBuffer recordQueryString = new StringBuffer();

recordQueryString.append("select FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME from ACTORS where lastname in (:lastnamevalues)");

List nameInvolvements = this.namedparameterJdbcTemplate.query(recordQueryString.toString(), namedParameters, new MyMapper());
```

Answer (score 25):

You can also use [MapSqlParameterSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/MapSqlParameterSource.html)

```
String query = "SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM ACTORS WHERE LASTNAME in (:LASTNAME)";
Set<String> ids = ....;

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("LASTNAME", ids);

this.namedparameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for the case where I had a Set of more than one String object

Comment: @Jayamohan What is need of `query.toString()`, when it is already in String format

Comment: I think it is not required

Comment: I have removed it

Comment: This here should be the accepted answer. It's a far better approach.