# Passing value to sql IN using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am trying to pass List in sql IN but I am getting invalid column type error. Here my SQL looks like:

```
String partyIdSql = "select party_id from myPartySearch where partyId = :id"
List<Long> partyIdList = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
  .queryForList(partyIdSql, new Object[] { id }, Long.class);


String currentRecordSql = "select * from myTable where someCol IN (:colVal)";
Map<String,Object>  params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("partyIdList", partyIdList);

memberInfo =  new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    .query(currentRecordSql , 
           new Object[] { params }, 
           new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyDto>(MyDto.class));
```

Comment: @Nathan Hughes - jdbctemplate

Comment: Use a [MapSqlParameterSource with a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698678/1813382), like suggested earlier.

Comment: use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16362128/217324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Map<String,Object> params = Collections.singletonMap("fields", partyIdList );    
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from myTable where someCol IN (:fields)", new Object[] { params }, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyDto>(MyDto.class));
```