# jdbcTemplate query serialized

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Having a query as:

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends String> getLocalizadoresMigradoSolr(
        Set<Integer> idEventosSet, Set<Integer> idSesionSet, Set<Integer> idCanalSet, Set<Integer> idPuntoVentaSet,
        Set<Integer> idTerminalSet, Set<Integer> idMetodoEntregaSet, Set<Integer> idTipoProductoSet) {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("SELECT DISTINCT(orden.localizador) ");
    query.append("FROM ob_compras.compras_datos_orden orden ");
    query.append("INNER JOIN ob_compras.compras_producto_orden producto ON producto.idOrden = orden.idOrden ");
    query.append("WHERE ");
    query.append("producto.idSesion IN(?)");
    query.append(" OR ");
    query.append(" producto.idEvento IN(?)");
    query.append(" OR");
    query.append(" orden.idCanal IN(?)");
    query.append(" OR");
    query.append(" orden.idPuntoVenta IN(?) ");
    query.append("OR ");
    query.append("orden.idTerminal IN(?)");
    query.append(" OR");
    query.append(" orden.metodoEntrega IN(?)");
    query.append(" OR");
    query.append(" orden.metodoEntrega IN(?)");

    List<String> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query.toString(), String.class, idSesionSet, idEventosSet, idCanalSet,
            idPuntoVentaSet, idTerminalSet, idMetodoEntregaSet, idTipoProductoSet);
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orden.localizador) FROM ob_compras.compras_datos_orden orden INNER JOIN     ob_compras.compras_producto_orden producto ON producto.idOrden = orden.idOrden WHERE     producto.idSesion IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?    @\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR  producto.idEvento IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR orden.idCanal IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR orden.idPuntoVenta IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR orden.idTerminal IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR orden.metodoEntrega IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x') OR orden.metodoEntrega IN(_binary'¬í\0sr\0java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4\0\0xpw\0\0\0?@\0\0\0\0\0\0x');
```

Why sets are been serialized? It should filling dynamic values on sql query but it does't. Instead, if serializing all parameters sets and becaming an slow and ugly query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets and array aren't supported. Use namedParameterJdbcTemplate instead

See

[How to use SELECT IN clause in JDBCTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504592/how-to-use-select-in-clause-in-jdbctemplates)

and

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/43428-in-clause-with-jdbctemplate